# clipDrawable wont allow rendering

Tags: android

My goal is to create a "thermometer" which grows at a higher number and shrink at a smaller number. Like a thermometer. So in code I design an bitmap drawable and pass it to clipDrawable. The image renders perfectly right up until I pass it to clip drawable, then I get nothing.

my main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TestView testView;
    private Timer timer;
    private int delay = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        testView = (TestView) findViewById(R.id.test_view);
        timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                testView.update();
            }
        }, 0, delay);
    }
}
```

My view class:

```
public class TestView extends View {

    private Paint rectPaint;
    private Paint barPaint;
    private Rect coverRect;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;
    private int SIZE = 200;

    //Defaults
    private int def_background = Color.BLACK;

    private Resources res;
    private Bitmap colorbarMap;
    private BitmapDrawable colorbarDraw;
    private ClipDrawable colorbarClip;
    private ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver;

    private int max = 100;
    private int min = 0;
    private int view_height;
    private int view_width;
    private boolean startup = true;

    //Customizable
    private int set_background;

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        readAttrs(context, attrs, 0);
        init();
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        readAttrs(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        readAttrs(context, null, 0);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        //System
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        res = getResources();
        viewTreeObserver = getViewTreeObserver();
        if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    view_width = getWidth();
                    view_height = getHeight();
                    afterLayout();
                }
            });
        }

        //Paints
        rectPaint = new Paint();
        barPaint = new Paint();

        //Shapes
        coverRect = new Rect();

        //Ints-floats-doubles
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        x2 = 100;
        y2 = 100;

        rectPaint.setColor(set_background);
        rectPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        coverRect.set(x, y, x2, y2);
    }

    public void update(){
        if(!startup) colorbarClip.invalidateSelf();
        postInvalidate();
    }

    private void afterLayout(){
        //Images - Create resource directory object, use it to set an image to a bitmap
        //  object using bitmap factory and scale it. Then create a drawable using that bitmap.
        //  Set the bounds of the new drawable bitmap. Assign it to a clip object for partial rendering
        colorbarMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.colorbar);
        colorbarMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(colorbarMap, view_width, view_height, true);
        colorbarDraw = new BitmapDrawable(res, colorbarMap);
        colorbarDraw.setBounds(0, 0, view_width, view_height);
        colorbarClip = new ClipDrawable(colorbarDraw, Gravity.BOTTOM, ClipDrawable.VERTICAL);
        colorbarClip.setLevel(10000);

        startup = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(set_background);
        if(!startup) colorbarClip.draw(canvas);
    }

    private void readAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TestView, defStyleAttr, 0);
            set_background = a.getInteger(R.styleable.TestView_set_background, def_background);
        a.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
        int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);
        setMeasuredDimension(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);
    }

    private int chooseDimension(int mode, final int size) {
        switch (mode) {
            case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                return size;
            case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
            default:
                return SIZE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(final Parcelable state) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        Parcelable superState = bundle.getParcelable("superState");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(superState);

        x2 = bundle.getInt("x2");
        y2 = bundle.getInt("y2");
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        Bundle state = new Bundle();
        state.putParcelable("superState", superState);

        state.putInt("x2",x2);
        state.putInt("y2",y2);

        return state;
    }
}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:testview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="prospect_industries.viewobject.MainActivity">

    <prospect_industries.viewobject.TestView
        android:id="@+id/test_view"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        testview:set_background="-16776961" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Trust me when I say I really have done my best at trying to find a solution to my problem before coming here. I cant figure out what I might be missing or what concept I might not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody answered, I will post an answer for future passersby. I did end up figuring out what I was doing wrong. The BitmapDrawable and the ClipDrawable have bounds in which must both be set before the image can be drawn. If that is not done correctly then you will get no rendering.